# Make selected item fit on one line, not two

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a very simple select and when I click on the menu it shows 3 options, all on one-line each. However, when I select an item, it shows it on 2 lines: 1 line for the text and another for the icon. How do I make it so it is one line?

```
import "./styles.css";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";

const items = ["a", "b", "c"];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>Please select an option</InputLabel>
        <Select required defaultValue="hi" fullWidth>
          {items.map((item, idx) => (
            <MenuItem key={idx} value={item}>
              <ListItemText primary={item} />
              <ListItemIcon>
                <EditIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        <FormHelperText>Just select something already</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-stallman-9brmk?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MenuItem` layout is flex, while `SelectInput` is not, you can target the `SelectInput` using `classes` props and override the layout style like this:

See all possible rule names to override [here](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#css).

```js
<Select classes={{ select: classes.root }}
```

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67030656/make-selected-item-fit-on-one-line-not-two#67030695]

Answer (score 1):

You're using flex properties in .MuiListItemText-root and .MuiListItemIcon-root, but parent still has display: block. Your CSS for .MuiInputBase-input should look like this (changed `display: block;` to `display: flex;`):

```
.MuiInputBase-input {
    font: inherit;
    color: currentColor;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    height: 1.1876em;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 0 7px;
    min-width: 0;
    background: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    animation-name: mui-auto-fill-cancel;
    letter-spacing: inherit;
    animation-duration: 10ms;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
```